# How do I edit a gem and then hard link it to a project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

So I have a gem in /vendor/bundle that needed to be fixed, and when I edit one of the files and then run bundle install it links up properly and all is good.  But the problem is that when I deploy my project, the edits to my gem are lost because it runs bundle and saves the gems in a separate shared directory.

It seems that the solution to this is to make a vendor/static_gems directory, and place the gem inside of there, and link it like:

```
gem 'ruby-mysql', :path => "vendor/static_gems/ruby-mysql-2.9.3"
```

But I get an error that the gem is not found.  is there something wrong with my path?  Or something wrong with what I am placing there?  When I copy this gem from the gems/ folder all that is in there is a lib/ directory with some .rb files.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't deploy your `Gemfile.lock` with your project, so Bundler runs without (or more probably) with an outdated one that links to the other gem path.

Be sure to update the `Gemfile.lock` with the rest of your project and you shouldn't need to worry about a static gem path or something like that.

Comment: So include a vendor/bundle directory and don't use the capistrano shared directory for gems?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the right idea, but I wasn't putting the whole gem into the static_gem folder, just the lib directory.  It works great when the whole gem is in there.